# Alphabetically Order chars in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Okay, just learnt LINQ syntax about ten minutes ago, made a first program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    char[] letters = {'d','a','C','n','D','e','R','f'};

    List<char> tokens = 
        (from l in letters
         where char.IsLower(l)  
         select l).ToList();
}
```

Now, as I was skimming through it, I saw an `orderby` keyword. But I can't grasp it's usage or capabilities. For example, in this case, can it be used to alphabetically order the tokens? If so, then how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var tokens = 
        (from l in letters
         where char.IsLower(l)
         orderby l
         select l).ToList();
```

This will sort it according to ASCII value. If you want to sort simply, alphabetically try this:

```
var tokens = 
        (from l in letters
         orderby char.ToLower(l)
         select l).ToList();
```

this will take all chars from `letters`, not only these where `char.IsLower(l) == true`

Comment: `orderby char.ToLower(l)` does not sort alphabetically, but will sort the upper cased characters before the lower cased characters.

Comment: char.ToLower(l) makes 'A' and 'a' the same for ordering, what should make the input data be sorted into: acdDefnR. Am I wrong?

Comment: `char.ToLower(l)` returns `true` or `false`, so `orderby char.ToLower(l)` orders by `true` and `false`. There are just two unique values to sort by, so basically the list stays unordered, but with all lower case characters last. Try it out ;-)

Comment: Are you sure what you are talking about? I used TOLower and you are talking about ISLower. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhef7hhe.aspx: Return Value Type: System.Char

Answer (score 1):

*@Marcin* said everything. 
But if you want the fluent syntax look here:

```
var tokens = letters.Orderby(l => l.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Comment: Everyone can become a part of [Anonymous Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(group)).

Comment: frankly, they freak me out. o_O . Also, I don't really understand their goals. What are they trying to achieve?

Comment: Guarantee the freedom of information, expression and comunication.